# Is possible to identify the LXC unprivileged container owner of process?

Tags: lxc

I have a linux server, Debian buster with LXC configured for unprivileged containers.
I have also a lot of crash from sssd_be, dmesg from server said:

```
dmesg|grep segfault

sssd_be[6739]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f080b190714 sp 00007ffc24a170a8 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7f080b15d000+52000]
sssd_be[7517]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fec6ca4f714 sp 00007ffc71eec028 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7fec6ca1c000+52000]
sssd_be[8853]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f9d181be714 sp 00007ffd42f784e8 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7f9d1818b000+52000]
sssd_be[15961]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f1560855714 sp 00007ffc784710e8 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7f1560822000+52000]
sssd_be[16728]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fa83b9df714 sp 00007fff1432b228 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7fa83b9ac000+52000]
sssd_be[30789]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f0c21213714 sp 00007ffd37808908 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7f0c211e0000+52000]
sssd_be[13515]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f67fd079714 sp 00007ffdae2dac78 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7f67fd046000+52000]
sssd_be[26637]: segfault at 8 ip 00007fa775531714 sp 00007ffd3bd1b9a8 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7fa7754fe000+52000]
sssd_be[4466]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f10cc150714 sp 00007ffe8e909a08 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7f10cc11d000+52000]
sssd_be[11382]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f0bcddee714 sp 00007fffcd021998 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.19.7[7f0bcddbb000+52000]
```

I want to identify the container in which the process running is causing the crash, how to do?
htop report openvz container names, but not the lxc container name.
So I tried ps but very strange result appear

```
 ps -efww -O lxc
  PID LXC      S TTY          TIME COMMAND
31825 -        S pts/9    00:00:00 bash
 1478 -        R pts/9    00:00:00  \_ ps
```

Any way to see the name of container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.
Using ansible, and create a script which domain is running sssd_be

```
#!/bin/sh
pgrep -a sssd
cat /etc/hostname
```

I run the script with this "playbook" which show on stdout the result

```
- name: Transfer and execute a script.
  hosts: all
  become_user: root
  tasks:
  - script: script.sh
    register: results
  - debug:
      var: results.stdout
```

After running the script I had found two domains with the process sssd_be, so I disable sssd for that machine and now works fine.